# What is the image interpolation algorithm that used in Office word 2013?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ms-office

I inserted an image into an office word(version 2013) document and drag its corner to enlarge its size,and I found that the enlarged image(the first one) has a very good resolution,even better than the image that I process with bicubic/bilinear interpolation in MATLAB(the second one). So I wonder what the algorithm it is that used in word?

Image1 is the enlarged image in Word 2013:

[image]

Image2 is the interpolation in MATLAB:

[image]

Comment: Bicubic and bilinear are different interpolations.... The first image looks like bilinear interpolation over a grid way bigger than the second one (wich probably is bicubic).

Comment: Matlab does not change pixel size if you enlarge a figure. If you want to increase the number of pixels, you need to use e.g. `interp2`. Note that currently, the Matlab image contains a lot more information than the Word image that suffers from quite some artifacts already.

Comment: What's displayed is rather different from what data exist.  First check to see what size your pixel array is, then check the dynamic range of pixel values.  *Then*  plot the data with some better tool than Matlab or Word so you can control the grayscale resolution.